# Запуск телеграмм-бота на Heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь запустить бота через Heroku
Все идет отлично до момента с sqlite3

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> Installing python-3.6.8
-----> Installing pip
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
Collecting sqlite (from -r /tmp/build_e23010ab13d9d8d3c44dee40e46de3f7/requirements.txt (line 2))
         Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sqlite (from -r /tmp/build_e23010ab13d9d8d3c44dee40e46de3f7/requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: )
       No matching distribution found for sqlite (from -r /tmp/build_e23010ab13d9d8d3c44dee40e46de3f7/requirements.txt (line 2))
     !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
     !     Push failed
```

В файле requirements.txt указано:

```
telebot
sqlite3>2.4.0
```

Даже если просто стоит `sqlite3`, то выдает эту же ошибку
Подскажите, что делать

Comment: No matching distribution found for telebot**s**

Comment: Зачем в requirements указан sqlite3, если он и так входит в стандартную библиотеку? И почему в requirements sqlite3, а в ошибке sqlite?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev , а разве он входит в стандартную библиотеку? Если да, то извините, пожалуйста. Забыл

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Спасибо большое